Is $E\left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N g_N(X_i^N)\right] = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega g_N(x)\;\mathrm{d}x$ if $X_i^N$ are iid uniformly distributed?
Suppose I have $X_i^N$ for $i=1, ..., N$ where $X_i^N$ is iid and sampled from the uniform distribution of some domain $\Omega$. Let me consider the sum
$$S_N := \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N g_N(X_i^N)$$
where $g_N\colon \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function.
Is is really true that
$$E[S_N] = \frac{1}{|\Omega|}\int_\Omega g_N(x)\;\mathrm{d}x?$$
Using the linearity of expectation and the iid nature of $X_i^N$, it seems true. But the function $g_N$ also depends on $N$ and as do the sampled points... Therefore I wonder if I missed something.

Using linearity of expectation and the fact that the $X^N_i$ are identically distributed, you have $E[S_N] = E[g_N(X^N_1)]$. The integral follows by LOTUS. I'm not sure why the fact that $g_N$ depends on $N$ is an issue; the equation you want to prove is for a fixed $N$.
